# How do i change time according to select timezone

Tags: javascript

HTML

```
<span class="time_zone"> 21:45 </span> 
<span class="time_zone"> 17:00  </span>
 <span class="time_zone"> 01:00 </span> <br> <br>
<select id="country" >
 <option value=""></option>
 <option value="UTC+5.30">India</option>
 <option value="UTC+10.00">Austrelia</option>
 <option value="UTC+2.45">Turkey</option>
 <option value="UTC-8.00">USA & Canada</option>
 <option value="UTC-10.00">Hawaii</option>
</select>
```

I want when  user select country from select tag than above time(which in UTC) change with respect that(also change date) .

Comment: Have you tried anything or starting from scratch here??

Comment: i try to add  or subtract  that value in span tag but when it come to change decimal to 59 or fix 23 max time feel like very difficult

Comment: What do you mean with changing time? Do you want to show a different span per selection or do you want to add the value of the selected option to the values of the spans?

Comment: Could you please post the jquery you already have?

Comment: It's like football match timing and user from different nation want to see in their timing

Comment: @Rohit416  i try very bad concept that's why i don't want show on above  [https://jsfiddle.net/gauravfifa/ydruj2bw/]

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [moment.js timezone library](http://momentjs.com/timezone/) , you just give it a time and the zone you want and it will work out the correct time.

e.g. from the docs

```
var newYork    = moment.tz("2014-06-01 12:00", "America/New_York");
var losAngeles = newYork.clone().tz("America/Los_Angeles");
var london     = newYork.clone().tz("Europe/London");

newYork.format();    // 2014-06-01T12:00:00-04:00
losAngeles.format(); // 2014-06-01T09:00:00-07:00
london.format();     // 2014-06-01T17:00:00+01:00
```